# FCM push notification is not received in production environment (Laravel/Flutter)

Tags: laravel, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

Just curious if anyone can suggest a possible reason on why FCM push notification was not received in production environment but was successful in staging environment?

Currently, the application has a lot of notifications and somehow this particular notification was not able to receive the push notification (in production) while the other notification are working fine. All the notification shares the same function to send the notification trough FCM (in Laravel), and since other notification works just fine, I don't think the function of creating the FCM have issues.

The current problematic notification is basically a Birthday notification, which will send notification to all users if there's a someone's birthday today. The notification was able to be received in the database but the push notification was not received (in production). And the staging environment was successful to received the push notification.

Currently I cannot think of any possible reason why this is happening since the notification works in staging environment and not in production, while other types of notification works in both staging and production.

Answer (score 0):

You have to register sha-256 and sha-1 which you got from playstore into firebase

Comment: Do you mind explaining why? If the sha-256 and sha-1 is not registered in firebase, does it means that there should be no push notification at all? Because currently other push notification works fine except the Birthday notification.